# Search for item in list with 2MILLION items - Python

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, search

I have a list of strings made of **1.9-2 MILLION items**.

The following code:

```
items = [...]
item_in_list = items[-1] in items
```

takes **0.1 seconds**

With **sqlite3** it takes **0.7 seconds**

---

Now **problem is I need to perform this check 1 million times** and I would like to complete this within minutes rather than days.

More precisely I'm trying to sync contents of a CSV file with the computed values within a DB.

---

**Any ideas?** Would be really great :)

Comment: `items[-1] in items` will always be `True` unless the list is empty (in which case it will raise an `IndexError`). Are you sure that's the right code?

Comment: like Amber, I'm wondering do you really want to know if the last item of a list in in the list ?

Comment: I guess "I'm trying to sync contents of a CSV file with the computed values within a DB" means that you either want to dump a database to cvs or load from cvs ... how does that involve checking of anything?

Comment: @Amber `items[-1] in items` was just a `benchmark` for the code, not the real code :)

Comment: Why **are** you **bolding** every **other** word **in** your **question**?  It's **distacting** and **doesn't** improve **it** in **any** way.

Comment: sqlite3 uses a binary search.. of course, a set would be faster as noted below.

Comment: I think the commenter's point was "items[-1] in items" doesn't do anything, at all, it doesn't search for a random item in items and while I'm not a low level python interpreter expert, I would expect that it can optimize items[-1] in items and replace it with True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both collections into frozensets.

little performance test:

```
import random
from timeit import Timer

def random_strings(size):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    min = 3
    max = 8
    strings = []
    for count in xrange(1, size):
        current = ''
        for x in random.sample(alpha, random.randint(min,max)):
            current += x  
        strings.append(current)
    return strings

string_list_1 = random_strings(10000)
string_list_2 = random_strings(10000)

def string_test():
    common = filter(lambda x: x in string_list_2, string_list_1)
    return common

def set_test():
    string_set_1 = frozenset(string_list_1)
    string_set_2 = frozenset(string_list_2)
    common = string_set_1 & string_set_2
    return common

string_timer = Timer("__main__.string_test()", "import __main__")
set_timer = Timer("__main__.set_test()", "import __main__")
print string_timer.timeit(10)
# 22.6108954005
print set_timer.timeit(10)
#  0.0226439453
```

As you can see, set is exponentially faster. Should perform better than dictionary, too.

Of important note is that I included the time necessary to make the sets. This overhead will affect your performance, too, but with the exception of having one set that is much much smaller than the other, you'll net a large gain.

Comment: As for how much faster it is, theoretically, checking a list is O(n)and checking a set is O(1). Checking a dict should be O(1) as well.

Comment: Yes and no. Those are the correct computational complexities of searching those data structures. But a dictionary requires more memory (as for as I understand) because it has to store a value for each hashable key. Since more memory usage can be a higher strain on garbage collection and memory allocation, cause more cache misses, force the use of the pagefile, etc., a set should, in the context of the larger computing environment, execute faster.

Answer (score 1):

For a search like this I would go with a binary search. One of the fasted methods for long SORTED lists. If it isn't sorted, then don't use binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You have two million strings that you need to match against one million other strings‽

A couple of things to try:

1. Use a set instead of a list for those 2 million items.
2. If that doesn't speed it up, try having the strings as keys in a dictionary.
3. If that also doesn't help, get a nice binary tree implementation and use that.

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, sets and dicts don't use binary trees, they use hash tables. This should be faster than a list, and in fact probably even faster than a binary search.

Comment: Sets and dicts both use hashes internally. They both offer O(1) membership test (keys only for dicts, of course) and are equally fast in practice, but a dict with bogus/unneeded values wastes a lot mote space (1.5 times for 1000 ints and `None` keys in my test, a lot more if you're acting very stupid)

Comment: neither sets nor dicts have sorted traversal capability, they use hash tables.  I don't see any reason to expect a sorted container to perform any better for this specific problem (membership test) than a hash table, in fact it's probably worse, since hash lookup is ammortized O(1) and bisection is O(log(n))

Comment: Ah! Right you both are, it's hash tables. Still, speed improvement should happen! :-)

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head, with so little info on why you are doing this a few million times:

1.) can you import the csv into a table and do the checks in sql?

2.) how about sorting and indexing the list for quick access?

cheers,
P

Comment: She mentioned SQLite, with no improvement.

Comment: getting the target row in sql might be slow, but importing and substituting an sql statement for the million iterations might be worth a try